# How can I export a variable inside of an anonymous function to the global scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have this code

```
((function(){
var a=2;
var b=3;
var c=b+a;
alert(c);//alert 5
})());
alert(c); //no alert
```

My question is which ways I can exports c to the global scope?
If you can give all the ways.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var c = ((function(){
    var a=2;
    var b=3;
    var c=b+a;
    alert(c);//alert 5
    return c;
})());
alert(c);
```

There are any number of ways to do this. You could implicitly or explicitly do property assignment on the global as well:

```
window.c = b+a;
this.c = b+a;
c = b+a;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple! All global variables in JavaScript are actually a child attribute of the "window" object, so declaring a variable in global scope adds makes that variable an attribute of the window object. From your anonymous function, you can place 'c', or other variables into a global scope simply by doing the following...

```
window.c=b+a;
alert(c); // Same!
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var c=0;
((function(){
    var a=2;
    var b=3;
    c=b+a;
    alert(c);//alert 5
})());

alert(c); //no alert
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function (window) {
    // this is local
    var c = 'local';
    
  // export to the global scope
    window.c = c || '';
})(window); // Pass in a reference to the global window object

console.log(c) // => 'local'
```

You can also pass in few other objects and that is not only limited to just one. [Here](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) is a really good explanation of how it works